# restrict access to staging and dev slots

Tags: azure, iis, web, url-rewriting, web-config

I need to restrict access to staging and dev slots of my website. So I add this rule in web.config ( as described [here](https://learnwithshahriar.wordpress.com/2015/08/06/azure-website-101-restrict-access-on-your-staging-site/) )

```
<rule name="Block unauthorized IP to staging/dev sites" stopProcessing="true">

    <match url=".*" />

    <conditions>
      <!-- Enter your staging site host name here as the pattern-->
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="myapp\-dev.azurewebsites.net"  />
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="myapp\-staging.azurewebsites.net" />

      <!-- Add the white listed IP addresses with a new condition as seen below -->
      <!-- <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="123\.123\.123\.2" negate="true"/> -->
    </conditions>

   <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="www.google.fr"/>
  </rule>
```

I need to restrict access to

1. http://myapp-dev.azurewebsites.net
2. http://myapp-staging.azurewebsites.net

It still accessibles. So I need to know how can I fix this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is to match all conditions, but you need to match only one, since it is either the dev or staging site. You need to add logicalGrouping="MatchAny", also you need to add http:// to www.google.fr. Below rule should work:

```
<rule name="Block unauthorized IP to staging/dev sites" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="myapp\-dev.azurewebsites.net" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="myapp\-staging.azurewebsites.net" />
        <!-- Enter your staging site host name here as the pattern-->
        <!-- Add the white listed IP addresses with a new condition as seen below -->
        <!-- <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="123\.123\.123\.2" negate="true"/> -->
      </conditions>

      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.google.fr" />
</rule>
```